# How to click a button using React Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a card in React using Material UI like this:

[image]

The `Sign out` is a button, I can change the state of it like `disable` from `true` to `false` by using React developer tools. But can I press the button by the developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Devtools don't contain DOM-specific functionality.

Currently selected React element is available as `$r` temporary variable in console. In case DOM button element is selected, click event can be triggered with:

```
$r.click()
```

React elements can be inspected in React Devtools. If `onClick` prop is provided, it can be saved to temporary variable (*Store as global variable*) and called from console:

```
$tmp()
```

Comment: I think it should be `$r.click` (no parentheses).

Comment: @quanpham0805 `click` is a function. If you use it without parentheses, it won't be called.